# How to include Volley in Unity plugin?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, jar, android-volley

I have a small Android plugin that I am using in conjunction with Unity. The plugin is supposed to ping a server with Lat - Long coordinates every few minutes.

I was able to get the plugin to successfully start in the background and log the coordinates, however sending a network request is giving me trouble. I am using Volley to send the requests but I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError at Lcom./android/volley/toolbox/Volley`

In my Android studio project I have included

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

in my build.gradle file. I also then do a MakeJar gradle build like so

```
task makeJar(type: Copy) {
  from('build/libs/')
  into("$buildDir")
  include('app.jar')
  rename ('app.jar', 'BackgroundGPS.jar')
}
```

Unity needs  .jar or .aar for plugins and I think I'm just not including Volleys source files correctly. I have tried a few other suggestions from other posts but nothing has helped. The specific line that throws the class not found error is:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

and opening the .jar file generated has a folder called `com/android/volley`, but it is empty. Anyone have any ideas? My theory is I'm just not including the volley files correctly but everyone says to just put the compile line in the build.grade, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this, all I did to get it working was include a volley.jar into the Plugins/Android folder.

Comment: You need to build what's called a fat, uber, or shaded jar for all jar files to be bundled into one. See the shadow jar  Gradle plugin